# Need sharepoint data related answer

Tags: sharepoint

1. How list/library data stored in sharepoint

   2. How/Where Document are saved in sharepoint
   3. Where configurations are saved in sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

In short all these things Lists, Documents and Configurations go into SQL Server Databases, Content DBs and configuration dbs. You should go to [SharePoint.SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheVillageIdiot said, nearly all configuration is stored in SQL. That said, there's no support from Microsoft for querying the SQL directly; they have API's for supported access.

Files "feel" like they're stored on a network file share because of the WebDAV service. Lists "feel" like they're stored in a server-grade Access database because of the ODBC drivers.

Although most configurations are stored in SQL, some of them are in the web.config and other files in SharePoint's IIS virtual directories.